# Create a list of thymeleaf fragments and pss it as param to another fragment

Tags: thymeleaf

Is it possible to statically initialize list of fragments and pass them as a parameter to another fragment? Something like this:

this:

```
<div th:fragment="links(name)" xmlns:th="http://www.w3.org/1999/html" th:remove="tag">
    <span th:replace="~{fthis::htmlIconTemplate(${name}, '')}"/>
</div>

<th:block th:replace="fragments/new/template1 :: standartTemplate('', ${content}, { {{~{this::links('live')}, ~{this::links('live')}}})">
</th:block>
```

template1:

```
<tr th:fragment="standartTemplate(mode, content, customFragments)" xmlns:th="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<th:block th:replace="${customFragments.get(1)}"/>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this fully answers your question. In the example below, the heart of the solution is this line:

```
<th:block th:replace = "__${#strings.listSplit(customFragments, ',')[1]}__">
```

The example builds up to this, starting from simpler cases. Because I don't have some of the wider context of your code, this would have to be adapted, of course, to your specific situation.

### The Set-Up

Contents of `frags_demo.html` - placed in the `resources` folder:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
    <head>
        <title>Fragments Demo</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    </head>
    <body>
        <h2>Fragments Demo</h2>

        <h3>In-page fragment:</h3>
        <div th:fragment="links(name)" th:remove="tag">
            <div th:text="'Here is ' + ${name}"></div>
        </div>

        <h3>First example:</h3>
        <!-- simple example, with a string not fragment names -->
        <th:block th:replace = "/fragments/fragments_one.html :: fragment_a(
             mode = 'a mode', 
             content = ${content}, 
             customFragments = 'foo,bar,baz')">
        </th:block>

        <h3>Second example:</h3>
        <!-- example with hard-coded fragment names -->
        <th:block th:replace = "/fragments/fragments_one.html :: fragment_a(
             mode = 'a mode', 
             content = ${content}, 
             customFragments = '/frags_demo.html::links(\'foo\'),bar,baz')">
        </th:block>

        <h3>Third example:</h3>
        <!-- example with hard-coded fragment names, using the template fragment -->
        <!-- use the absolute fragment path & name - can't use 'this'            -->
        <th:block th:replace = "/fragments/fragments_one.html :: fragment_b(
             mode = 'a mode', 
             content = ${content}, 
             customFragments = '/frags_demo.html::links(\'foo\'),
                                /frags_demo.html::links(\'bar\'),
                                /frags_demo.html::links(\'baz\')')">
        </th:block>

    </body>
</html>
```

Contents of `fragments_one.html` - placed in a `fragments` sub-folder under the `resources` folder:

```
<!-- the customFragments parameter contains the string 'foo,bar,baz' -->
<th:block th:fragment="fragment_a(mode, content, customFragments)">

    <th:block th:text="${'Fragment A from fragments_one.html'}">
    </th:block>

    <!-- use the Thymeleaf listSplit function to create a list -->
    <!-- giving us ['foo', 'bar', 'baz']                       -->

    <!-- picking one of the items (the 2nd one - zero-indexed!): -->
    <div th:with="frag=${#strings.listSplit(customFragments, ',')[1]}"
         th:text="${frag}">
    </div>

    <!-- iterating through the entire list: -->
    <div th:each="frag : ${#strings.listSplit(customFragments, ',')}">
        <div th:text="${frag}"></div>
    </div>

</th:block>

<th:block th:fragment="fragment_b(mode, content, customFragments)">
    <div>The string representing the template:</div>
    <div th:with="frag=${#strings.listSplit(customFragments, ',')[1]}"
         th:text="${frag}">
    </div>

    <p/>
    <div>The invoked template:</div>
    <th:block th:replace = "__${#strings.listSplit(customFragments, ',')[1]}__">
    </th:block>

</th:block>
```

### The Output

When you hit the `frags_demo` page, the following is displayed in the browser:

```
Fragments Demo

In-page fragment:

Here is null

First example:

Fragment A from fragments_one.html
bar
foo
bar
baz

Second example:

Fragment A from fragments_one.html
bar
/frags_demo.html::links('foo')
bar
baz

Third example:

The string representing the template:
/frags_demo.html::links('bar')

The invoked template:
Here is bar
```

It is that very last line (`here is bar`) which represents the result of the parameterized fragment invocation.

### Walkthrough

I build up the complexity through the examples, to help clarify how things work.  The key points to note are:

Thymeleaf passes each fragment parameter as a string. So we use the built-in `#strings.listSplit` function to give us an iterable list. In my example it's comma-separated (`foo,bar,baz`). Depending on what ends up in the string, a comma may not be the right delimiter for you.

If you don't want to iterate through the full list, you can select any item with `[n]`.

Then in the demo we replace `foo,bar,baz` with three fragment references, to make the demo closer to what you want.

The final step is to use the preprocessing directive `__${...}__` to ensure the fragment selector is treated as a string by `th:replace`:

```
<th:block th:replace = "__${#strings.listSplit(customFragments, ',')[1]}__">
```

### Final Thought

If re-arranging templates and fragments could allow you to simplify, and avoid this complexity, then I would advocate for that, instead of this. But I don't know the larger context, so that may not be an option.